# Reference main Navbar in all website pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using bootstrap.

I have the navbar in the home page.

I would like to use the same navbar in all the pages of the website.

However as I keep adding content I will have to keep updating not only the main Navbar but also the navbar of the other pages.

Is there a way to link the navbar of all pages to the home navbar?

Comment: Your question is too broad given that there are numerous approaches depending on your preferences, the scope of your project, and what your hosting solution supports.  It could be anything from including HTML templates via JavaScript, to Server Side Includes, or full server side processing like PHP or Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the navbar in its own .php file, and include it like so:

```
<?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
```

Learn more about the include function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php